# add class to img where it's id eq num

Tags: jquery

I would like to add class to img where it's id = `<?PHP $numer ?>`
how can i do that?

```
<div id="dogSizeBox" class="col-md-4">
    <input id="dogSizeID" type="hidden" value="16" name="dog_details[size]">
    <img id="15" class="dogSize zebra_tips1" src="images/size1.png">
    <img id="16" class="dogSize zebra_tips1" src="images/size2.png">
    <img id="17" class="dogSize zebra_tips1" src="images/size3.png">
    <img id="18" class="dogSize zebra_tips1" src="images/size4.png">
</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
        var id = "<?PHP if (!empty($dog_details['size'])) echo $dog_details['size'];  else echo "0"; ?>";
         **$("#dogSizeBox #id").attr('id',id).addClass('border-highlight');**


        $(".dogSize").click (function () {
            var obj = this;
            $(obj).addClass('border-highlight');
            $("#dogSizeID").val($(obj).attr("id"));
            $(".dogSize").not(obj).removeClass('border-highlight');
        });

    </script>
```

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript doesn't expand variables inside strings, you have to use concatenation:

```
$("#" + id).addClass('border-highlight');
```

There's no point in using `.attr('id', id)` -- it already has that attribute. And there's no point in using `#dogSizeBox` in the selector; since IDs must be unique in the entire page, the container is redundant.